# CircleCi How to get name of merged branch?

Tags: circleci

How to get branch name in `.circleci/config.yaml?` When I merge feature/A to main, then How to get name of feature/A?

`'echo $CIRCLE_BRANCH'` print main name. However, I need name of feature/A!